# Installing CentOS and Windows Server on the Hypervisor

Tags: centos, virtualization, windows-server-2022, hypervisor

Hello Server Fault community,

In our company, we are planning to install an ERP system, and the system provider has specified the following server requirements of the application:

CPU: 1x CPU Intel Xeon >= 2.5GHz, 8M cache, 4 Cores
Storage: 2 x 128GB SSD, 2 x 500GB SSD or SAS (15K rpm)
RAM: 16GB
Operating System: CentOS
Considering our additional need for Windows Server,we are installing both CentOS and Windows Server using a hypervisor on the specified server.

I need advice on whether it's necessary to add  RAM or disks to accommodate this dual operating system setup.

Your insights and recommendations on the optimal configuration for running both CentOS and Windows Server on the same hardware would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: In general: vendor sizing recommendation are often understating actual production needs (or massively oversized) so running any product in a adjustable VM on a hypervisor that has sufficient capacity to assign  more resources when future needs arise is a good thing. A hypervisor with more CPU and RAM than you immediately need is always useful but the right amount of RAM and CPU  to buy now, versus possibly expanding that in the future, that really depends on your actual workloads

Comment: For capacity planning the resource requirements for hypervisors themselves are usually very modest, most of the resources of that physical server will be available to VM's.